# Как вызывать константы из библиотеки dll в PHP

Tags: php, com

Всем привет. Не могу разобраться в следующем.

У меня есть COM-библиотека(hybrid.dll) написанная на C++. В ней внутри есть список:

```
enum DECLSPEC_UUID("****") COLOR
{ green = 0x1,
black = 0x2,
 blue = 0x3
};
```

Вопрос. Как в PHP можно работать с такими списками (как мне вызвать этот список)?

Пытался вызывать как функцию

```
$PHP_LIB = new COM("HybridLib.HybridCOM") ;
$PHP_LIB -> COLOR("green");
```

Но ничего не получилось...

Заранее спасибо за уделенное время!

Comment: причем тут c# тег?

Comment: знаю как это на C# сделать: COMTest.ColorType((int)Lib.COLOR.RED, .....);

Comment: это хорошо, что знаете. Но это же не имеет отношения к вопросу

Comment: `$PHP_LIB = new COM("HybridLib.HybridCOM"); var_dump($PHP_LIB);` сделайте, что у вас будет?

Comment: object(com)#1 (0) { } Это вывелось

Answer (score 0):

Должно вот так сработать с enum:

```
$PHP_LIB = new \COM("HybridLib.HybridCOM") ;
$green = $PHP_LIB->COLOR->green;
```

Comment: Выводит ошибку. Вот что пишет. Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable to lookup `COLOR': Неизвестное имя.

Comment: а если так? $PHP_LIB->COLOR->{'green'};

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable to lookup `COLOR': Неизвестное имя...... 
Получается, что $PHP_LIB->COLOR........ Это уже не верно...

Comment: а если const GREEN = 0x1; $PHP_LIB->ColorType(GREEN, .....);

Comment: ... Call to undefined method com::ColorType() ... 
Не вариант((( Уже столько всего перепробовал...(

Comment: а дока по API к этой либе есть?